# The standard textbook on supernovae?

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, stars, supernova, stellar-evolution

This is a straightforward question:

What is considered to be the standard treatment of [supernovae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova)? Could be a textbook, lecture notes, review article, etc.

Comment: What aspect? nucleosynthesis, explosion models,  observations, etc?

Comment: Given that supernaovae are still a field of *very* active research I'd be surprised to find *any* books to speak of. By the time the fool thing came out of the bindery it's be out of date. Look, instead, for a relatively recent review article. Probably on arXiv.

Comment: I find Supernova Explosions by Branch and Wheeler 2017 is a very useful and comprehensive book. You should check it out. Here is the link: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783662550526